# Attach to wp-login.php and xmlrpc.php

Tags: htaccess, security, wp-login-form, xml-rpc, hacks

I am receiving many requests to my wp-login.php and xmlrpc file, now I just set up an htaccess to prevent requests to xmlrpc, but how do you suggest me to block wp-login?

thanks

Comment: I think I found myself an answer here... https://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to using htaccess, you can disable the XML-RPC function by adding the following to your child theme's `functions.php`:

```
# Set XML-RPC features to false
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'pre_option_enable_xmlrpc', '__return_zero' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it to paste in your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.*)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
</IfModule>
```

Replace `example.com` to your domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I advise to you protection plugin, like `iThemes Security`. It has the excellent feature:  to hide `wp-login.php` and instead, you can set custom url for login (and hackers cant find that url, of course, if you wont reveal that link in internet).